# Domain users aren't found on domain-joined machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, hyper-v, remote-desktop

I have Windows Server 2008 machine (VM) that I joined to a active directory domain (the DC is a 2K8 machine as well). It appears that the machine is joined, and I can log in to the machine as a domain user. However, some other stuff isn't working. I can't remote desktop into the machine even as a domain admin (just doesn't accept the credentials at all), and I can't add SQL logins for domain users (SQL says the user can't be found).

I created the VM using a VHD that I previously exported from the Hyper-V snap-in, and it seems to work fine for the DC VM I created. But this second VM is causing me grief. Any ideas?

Comment: Please find & post the event log errors/entries from the target server for the failed RDP session and the exact error message you receive from the RDP client.  
Is the target machine a DC?

Comment: I looked in the Windows Event Viewer log entries and didn't see anything. Is that where I should be looking? And, no, the target machine isn't a DC. The DC is a separate VM on the same hyper-v server.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the VM is still joined to the domain? Machines sometimes have their computer account details get out of sync when you start playing with VM images and replaying older instances of domain joined machines for example. Try changing it to a workgroup and rejoining it to the domain, that will clear up any issues if this is the problem.

Comment: Yeah, that was one of the first things I tried. No luck unfortunately.

Comment: But it does rejoin the domain without any issues? When an RDP session fails do you see anything indicating the reason for the failures in the security log?

Comment: It rejoins the domain just fine, and I can log in to the machine locally. I don't see anything relating to remote desktop in the log.